# ffserver documentation & Sample codes

Tags: android, streaming, ffserver

Since I have been experimenting live-streaming with Android 2.2, in my application I try to use ffserver & ffmpeg. I successfully ported ffmpeg to Android by using [Bambuser's](http://bambuser.com) build.

And now I want to use ffserver through it's configuration file. But I couldn't find much more documentation or sample codes for API usage. Does anybody know how I can get a well-written documentation or tutorial?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Official FFMPEG Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) for documentation on ffserver. It provides stream examples as well as detailed descriptions, tips, options and configuration syntax.  This has been the best detailed site for ffserver command structure I have found.